# How to get rid of an extra radio button choice created by SharePoint Lists?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, button, choices

I am creating a list on SharePoint and want to include a simple field in which users can answer a question by choosing a radio button. When I save my changes I see that Sharepoint has included an extra line (or choice) I simply wanted YES, NO and UNSURE as my options. I do not want an empty field. Any help would be great. [image]

Comment: You are likely to get better (and more) answers if you include more information in the question. Most importantly, edit the question to include your SharePoint version. If you give more detail on how you're creating this radio button object, that will also help give useful answers. Welcome to the site.

Comment: try to uncheck "Can add values manually"